# Test when throw error on instance Javascript class with missing parameters

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to use Jest to unit test, and didnt find how to test if class throws an error when it has missing parameters.

This is ScheduleJob.js

```
class ScheduleJob {
  constructor({ id, description, maxConclusionDate, estimateTime }) {
    if (id === undefined) {
      throw new Error("id is undefined");
    }
    if (description === undefined) {
      throw new Error("description is undefined");
    }
    if (maxConclusionDate === undefined) {
      throw new Error("maxConclusionDate is undefined");
    }
    if (estimateTime === undefined) {
      throw new Error("estimateTime is undefined");
    }
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.maxConclusionDate = maxConclusionDate;
    this.estimateTime = estimateTime;
  }
}

module.exports = ScheduleJob;
```

This is ScheduleJob.test.js

```
const ScheduleJob = require("./ScheduleJob.js");

describe("./ScheduleJob parameters validation", () => {
  it("creates a instance with all parameters", () => {
    const mockJob = {
      id: 1,
      description: "Importação de arquivos de fundos",
      maxConclusionDate: "2019-11-10 12:00:00",
      estimateTime: "2 horas",
    };
    const mockInstance = new ScheduleJob(mockJob);
    expect(mockInstance.id).toBe(1);
    expect(mockInstance.description).toBe("Importação de arquivos de fundos");
    expect(mockInstance.maxConclusionDate).toBe("2019-11-10 12:00:00");
    expect(mockInstance.estimateTime).toBe("2 horas");
  });
  it("Throws error when missing params", () => {
    const mockJob = {
      description: "Importação de arquivos de fundos",
      maxConclusionDate: "2019-11-10 12:00:00",
      estimateTime: "2 horas",
    };
    expect(new ScheduleJob(mockJob)).toThrow(Error);
  });
});
```

Maybe I have to mock this class and create an object with the errors, I've seen some posts with that answer, but the errors in that cases are throw by funcions and not by the constructor itself

Answer (score 0):

[.toThrow](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tothrowerror) executes a function passed in expect and verifies that it throws an error.

> Note: You must wrap the code in a function, otherwise the error will not be caught and the assertion will fail.

So, you should wrap the `new ScheduleJob(mockJob)` statement in a function like this:

```js
expect(() => new ScheduleJob(mockJob)).toThrow(Error);
```

Then, the test will pass. Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/62459652/scheduleJob.test.js (10.478s)
  ./ScheduleJob parameters validation
    ✓ creates a instance with all parameters (3ms)
    ✓ Throws error when missing params (4ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.037s, estimated 13s
```